# Adding items to array with while loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push 1 -> 10 into my "array1"  though I'm sure that it's not working.

```js
array1 = ["123", "abc", "string", "text", "test", "ok"]
                 while (i <= 10){
                    array1.push(i)
                    i++
                 }
    document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML = document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML + " | " + array[Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length))]
```

p0's innerhtml stays as *"Random Array Item:"* and does not change, though when I remove the while loop it seems to work fine, example output, *"Random Array Item: | test | text | abc | abc | text | abc"*

Comment: Would you like to put numbers as a key or concatenate into the values?

Comment: Looking at your variable names, this can't possibly work. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbdevch/wv5j9gtw/)

Comment: Your code works just fine, except you've used `array` instead of `array1` on the last line of the code snippet.

Comment: Press run snippet, it tells you what the problem is... I suggest you learn how to [debug javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error when referencing your array, as you are using `array` but your array is named `array1`. You need to change that in order to work:

```js
i=0;
array1 = ["123", "abc", "string", "text", "test", "ok"];
while (i <= 10){
    array1.push(i);
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML = document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML + " | " + array1[Math.floor((Math.random() * array1.length))];
```

```html
<p id="p0">Random Array Item</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the use case is just to push 1...10 into a new array, this will work.

```
var array1 = ["123", "abc", "string", "text", "test", "ok"],    
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].forEach(function(i){
 array1.push(i);
});

document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML = document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML + " | " + array1[Math.floor((Math.random() * array1.length))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow some adjustments:

```
var i = 0;
array1 = ["123", "abc", "string", "text", "test", "ok"]
             while (i <= 10){
                array1.push(i)
                i++
             }
document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML = document.getElementById("p0").innerHTML + " | " + array1[Math.floor((Math.random() * array1.length))]
```

basically, you just need to change the last variable from array to array1.